# Issues With Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

I am in an introductory Java course and am learning about inheritance.  I had to create a new method (getUserName) within superclass code that was already written to make  the private username variable public and it compiles and works well:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Post 

    private String username;  // username of the post's author
    private long timestamp;
    private int likes;
    private ArrayList<String> comments;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Post.
     * 
     * @param author    The username of the author of this post.
     */
    public Post(String author)
    {
        username = author;
        timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        likes = 0;
        comments = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    /**
     * Record one more 'Like' indication from a user.
     */
    public void like()
    {
        likes++;
    }

    /**
     * Record that a user has withdrawn his/her 'Like' vote.
     */
    public void unlike()
    {
        if (likes > 0) {
            likes--;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add a comment to this post.
     * 
     * @param text  The new comment to add.
     */
    public void addComment(String text)
    {
        comments.add(text);
    }

    /**
     * Return the time of creation of this post.
     * 
     * @return The post's creation time, as a system time value.
     */
    public long getTimeStamp()
    {
        return timestamp;
    }

    /**
     * Display the details of this post.
     * 
     * (Currently: Print to the text terminal. This is simulating display 
     * in a web browser for now.)
     */
    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println(username);
        System.out.print(timeString(timestamp));

        if(likes > 0) {
            System.out.println("  -  " + likes + " people like this.");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println();
        }

        if(comments.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("   No comments.");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("   " + comments.size() + " comment(s). Click here to view.");
        }
    }
    public String getUserName()
    {
        return username;
    }

    /**
     * Create a string describing a time point in the past in terms 
     * relative to current time, such as "30 seconds ago" or "7 minutes ago".
     * Currently, only seconds and minutes are used for the string.
     * 
     * @param time  The time value to convert (in system milliseconds)
     * @return      A relative time string for the given time
     */

    private String timeString(long time)
    {
        long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long pastMillis = current - time;      // time passed in milliseconds
        long seconds = pastMillis/1000;
        long minutes = seconds/60;
        if(minutes > 0) {
            return minutes + " minutes ago";
        }
        else {
            return seconds + " seconds ago";
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to call this method (within the printShortSummary method) in the subclass it won't compile:

```
`enter code here`import java.util.ArrayList;
`enter code here`public class MessagePost extends Post
{
    private String message;  // an arbitrarily long, multi-line message

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class MessagePost.
     * 
     * @param author    The username of the author of this post.
     * @param text      The text of this post.
     */
    public MessagePost(String author, String text)
    {
        super(author);
        message = text;
    }
    public String printShortSummary;
    {
        System.out.println("Message post from " + getUserName);

    }
    /**
     * Return the text of this post.
     * 
     * @return The post's message text.
     */
    public String getText()
    {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Comment: After doing some editing, this makes no sense, is printShortMemory a method?

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: errr you are not returning a string in the method!!

Answer (score 2):

`System.out.println("Message post from " + getUserName);`

Should be

`System.out.println("Message post from " + getUserName());`.

`getUserName()` is a method, and needs to have parentheses at the end of it even it has no arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
public String printShortSummary;
{
    System.out.println("Message post from " + getUserName);

}
```

to

```
public String printShortSummary()
{
    String username;
    System.out.println("Message post from " + getUserName());
    username = getUsername();
    return username;
}
```

**The rule**

Your method printShortSummary() must return a string value. And when you called a method don't forget the bracket (). Eventually your mistakes are mostly a typo, I'm suggesting you to use IDE like Netbeans or Eclipse so the mistake can be corrected easily.

Comment: Thanks for all the help everyone!  I'm still very green (obviously)

Answer (score 1):

Invoke the method as follows (with parenthesis):

```
System.out.println("Message post from " + getUserName());
```

Also, you either have to make the `printShortSummary` method void or return some string.

Answer (score 1):

You should call it as method man,
call it like this

```
System.out.println("Message post from " + getUserName());
```